# Shader code in OpenGl is not coming out right. What am I missing?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, glsl

Hello guys Im having alot of trouble with my shader my fragment and vertex. Im not sure what im really missing with this, Any help would be great. So far with my code I get this!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qgl6h2d3p3klu0/Screenshot%202015-05-02%2015.02.50.png?dl=0

But its suppose to look like this, what am I missing?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uy6093tbdtmcdux/Screenshot1.jpg?dl=0

Here is my code fragment code:

```
#version 150

in vec3 fN;
in vec3 fL;

in vec3 fE;             // NEW!  Coming in from the vertex shader

out vec4 fColor;

void main () {
vec3 N = normalize(fN);
vec3 L = normalize(fL);

vec3 E = normalize(-fE);    // NEW! Reverse E
vec3 H = normalize(L + E);  // NEW! Create the half vector  

// Diffuse component
float diffuse_intensity = max(dot(N, L), 100);
vec4 diffuse_final = diffuse_intensity*vec4(0.0, 0.0, 2.8, 2.0);
// NEW! Specular component
float spec_intensity = pow(max(dot(H, L), -1.5), 60);
vec4 spec_final = spec_intensity+vec4(0.0, 0.0, 2.8, 2.0);

fColor = diffuse_final + spec_final;
 }
```

And here is my vertex code:

```
 #version 150

 // Combined our old stuff with the shader from Angel book

 in vec4 vPosition;
 in vec4 vNormal;
 uniform mat4 mM;       // The matrix for the pose of the model
 uniform mat4 mV;       // The matrix for the pose of the camera
 uniform mat4 mP;       // The perspective matrix
 uniform mat4 mR;       // The rotation matrix

 uniform vec4 lightPosition;    //

 out vec3 fN;           
 out vec3 fL;

 out vec3 fE;


void main () {

fN = (mR*vNormal).xyz; //Rotate the normal! only take the first 3 parts, since fN is a vec3
fE = (mV*mM*vPosition).xyz;
fL = (lightPosition).xyz;       // In world space
gl_Position = mP*mV*mM*vPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I spot some issues with your code:

```
float diffuse_intensity = max(dot(N, L), 100);
```

This one does not make sense at all. As `N` and `L` are normalized, the dot product will be in [0,1], and that `max` will always yield 100. You want `max(..., 0)` there to just clamp negative values to 0.

This one

```
vec4 diffuse_final = diffuse_intensity*vec4(0.0, 0.0, 2.8, 2.0);
```

is not strictly wrong, but values out of [0,1] for the light color or material coefficient are at least unusual. It means that the value will easily clamp out of the representable range.

```
float spec_intensity = pow(max(dot(H, L), -1.5), 60);
```

Here, you repeat the `max` mistake again, just in the other direction. you again want `max(...,0)`.

Also, your are mixing your spaces. `L` is just the normalized *world space* light position, which is a completely meaningless value in itself, and E is the *eye space* viewing direction. You must use one spcae consistently. And `L` should be the direction vector from the *vertex* to the *light source*. not just the direction from world space origin.

```
vec4 spec_final = spec_intensity+vec4(0.0, 0.0, 2.8, 2.0);
```

Here, you are using this odd values again. However, this time, you use `+` instead of `*`, which is certainly not what you should do.

Comment: When you mean I want max(....,0) what would go in the ..... spot do I not really need dot?

Comment: yes, the dot products are in principle correct. It will provide the cosine of the angle between those two vectors, and this is exactly what the blinn-phong model you seem to be implementing is doing.

Comment: Am I on the right track? However im not getting the green and red look like that the model im suppose to look like is. Am I missing anything?

Comment: as you only have non-zero values  int he blue and alpha channels, you won't get red and green. I don't know what you are really trying to do, and how the red and green is supposed to come into beeing.

Comment: The only tip we were given was to create a shader based on the picture provided.

Comment: And this: 

The “normal” shader is just that.  It doesn’t use any light sources AT ALL.  Instead, it just uses the normal as its color.  Note that there’s a LARGE blue section.  This is because the sphere is close to the camera and the perspective matrix has deformed the geometry a bit.  If it were to use an orthographic projection, then you would see equal representations of green and red.

Comment: Well. If you want to just show your normals, you should do so.

Comment: How do I go about doing that tho? When he says that im not sure what hes asking for I mean the way I think it is seems to easy.

Comment: You don't need to calculate the lighting if your goal is just visualizing the normals. Ally you need to do is assign the (normalized) normal vector to the rgb part of the output, probably with a small transformation to map the [-1,1] range to [0,1].